# Filter Search and Free text search using Foursquare api

Tags: search, categories, foursquare

We are currently developing a food/restaurant search on our website using Foursquare API.

1. We have hit an issue which is the free text search. If I would like to search for a specific restaurant/food venue eg. "Lucilda Pizzeria" will it allow me to do so?
2. Can we use the Food Category in the Category tree https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree to allow people to filter the venues? Eg. "Minnesota" - "Bagel Shop"

Hope anyone can please clear up these questions for me.

Thanks to anyone who will get back to me with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the getting started guide to search: https://developer.foursquare.com/start, then read about the search and explore endpoints. In your use case, I would recommend making an explore API request with the `intent=food` parameter passed in.